# MongoDB and Docker via docker-compose auth error and not initalizing db

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I have read the [Mongo Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mongo/).
I need some help setting up a simple application.

I want a local mongodb that dumps / uses a database named "my_test_db"
and writes to `<project-dir>/mongo/my_test_db`

Here is my simple project:

```sh
# project structure
<project-dir>/
-- .env
-- docker-compose.yml
-- mongo/
-- + -- my_test_db/
```

The `.env` file:

```sh
# <project>/.env
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test_user
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test_pwrd
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my_test_db
MONGO_DATA_DIR=/mongo/my_test_db
MONGO_LOG_FILE=/mongo/mongodb.log
```

my attempt at `docker compose`:

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0

    # load env variables
    env_file:
      - .env 

    # map data_dir to host <project>/<data_dir>
    volumes:
      - ".${MONGO_DATA_DIR}:${MONGO_DATA_DIR}"

    expose:
      - 27017

    # set env vars with loaded vars (appears to be necessary for the user to be created, despite loading them with env_file)
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}

    # map ports
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    command: "mongod --smallfiles"
    container_name: mongodb-test
# --logpath=.${MONGO_LOG_FILE} # when added to command fails
```

then in two shells I have

```sh
#shell-1
<project-dir>$ docker-compose up

# I see my user created
# I see "MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=e19ea190b601" so my custom db isnt made on init...
```

```sh
#shell-2
# <project-dir>$ mongo 27017 --usernamne test_user --password test_pwrd # does fails to connect
<project-dir>$ mongo 27017 # connects



> db.getName()
# 27017 # so naming it didnt work

> show users
# Error: command usersInfo requires authentication

> use my_test_db
> db.myColl.insert({'name': 'test'})
# WriteCommandError({..., "codeName": "Unauthorized"})
```

I am currently testing on macOS (as docs state that this might be relevant)

What am I doing wrong? I understand the concept of docker but personally don't use it as it is a pain to get used too... but I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the authentication part: have you tried to add `--authenticationDatabase admin` in order to be able to login ?
- Regarding `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` it wont be effective unless you have a script under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` as shown in the [docker-entrypoiny.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L303-L313) that is used in the mongodb image so you can have a bash script in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` with that said.
- Using the root user as an owner for your application db is not a security wise as it will have the ability to control everything in the mongodb instance.

  IMHO a better approach would be adding extra variables like the following:

  - `MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE`
  - `MONGO_APPLICATION_USERNAME`
  - `MONGO_APPLICATION_PASSWORD`

  Then add a bash script that will create the user and assign it to the database by using environment variables ( you need to mount it to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d):

  > You might need to change the user role as you see fit.

  ```
  # initmongo/setup.sh
  mongo admin -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "db.getSiblingDB('$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE').createUser({user: '$MONGO_APPLICATION_USERNAME', pwd: '$MONGO_APPLICATION_PASSWORD', roles: [{role: 'readWrite', db: '$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE'}]});"
  ```

  In the docker-compose.yml add a volume to your current list of volumes

  ```
  #docker-compose.yml
  volumes:
    - ".${MONGO_DATA_DIR}:${MONGO_DATA_DIR}"
    - "./initmongo/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
  ```

  And finally remove this variable `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` as there is no need for it

  In order to login use the following command:

  > replace the variables with your actual values

  ```
  docker exec -it container_name mongo -u "$MONGO_APPLICATION_USERNAME" -p "$MONGO_APPLICATION_PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase "$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE" "$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE"
  ```
- For the `.env` file i am not sure what could cause this issue. do you have any warnings while using it ? Also Consider checking [this comment](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4223#issuecomment-342721426) or [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4223#issuecomment-338254181)

Comment: So where / how do I add the `docker-entrypoint` and want goesin that file? I am ok with root user for this app as it doesn't need to be secure. It is only ever going to be run locally

Comment: create a directory called `initmongo` and add `setup.sh` to it then update the `docker-compose.yml` to mount the directory. Answer updated

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. I added the file and made the changes.The script is run (according the the mongo log). However I can not log in as a user and if  I just connect to mongo the default db is again the port...

Comment: I have update the answer with how to login. can you try  it?

Comment: what exactly changed?

Comment: This command:  docker exec -it container_name mongo -u "$MONGO_APPLICATION_USERNAME" -p "$MONGO_APPLICATION_PASSWORD" --authenticationDatabase "$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE" "$MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE" change these variables with the actual values

Comment: I was using exact values :)

Comment: Okay please clarify the issue you have and ensure that you have dropped the old data directory before creating the new database as I tested these steps but I cannot detect your current issue

Comment: So it works now, I wasn't using `docker exec -it` just mongo. But if I write something the data doesnt go to host :/

Comment: It seems like you did not mounted the data directory of mongo. AFAIK  Mongodb data saved under /data/db so you need to add another volume for this so you can keep the data on your host

Comment: isn't that what `".${MONGO_DATA_DIR}:${MONGO_DATA_DIR}"` was suppose to do? or should that now be `./store_data_here/${MONGO_APPLICATION_DATABASE}`:/data/db`

Comment: The second one should work as expected. The first syntax won't work unless you pass --dbpath parameter with the new directory. So keep it simple and use the second way as long as you are able to keep the data.  I don't have an access to computer right now but I see that you use a variable for the DATA_DIR ensure it works as expected otherwise use the second way